# Assignments to the 'data' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

**There is a complete warning message:** Assignments to the 'data' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.

I am trying to use data state which is in the useState Hook in Material Table to display the data. That's why i change const to let, But its keep giving me a warning and i dont know how to use useRef Hook with useState Hook.

```
const filterrr = () => {
    
    
            if (age.length !== 0) {
              return true;
            } 
            else {
              return false;
            }
        
          }
    
          let [data, setData] = useState(Data);
    
    
          useEffect(() => {
    
    
            console.log(Data);
            data = Data.filter(filterrr);
            setData(data);
          }, [age])
```

so i am trying to use useState outside the useEffect so other functions can use data state.

Comment: Please don't name your variable "filterrr".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React `useState()` variables are immutable i.e. you cannot directly modify `data` just by declaring it with the `let` keyword. To clear this warning, modify your code as follows:

```js
const filterrr = useCallback(() => {
  if (age.length !== 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}, [age]);

const [data, setData] = useState(Data);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("oldData", data);
  const newData = Data.filter(filterrr);
  console.log("newData", newData);
  setData(newData);
}, [filterrr]);
```

I have used `useCallback()` to wrap the `filterrr()` method so that we can add it to `useEffect()` dependencies array, this is a good practice in general.

If you don't need `filterrr()` method elsewhere in your code, simply move it inside `useEffect()` without the `useCallback()`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const filterrr = () => {
    if (age.length !== 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  console.log("oldData", data);
  const newData = Data.filter(filterrr);
  console.log("newData", newData);
  setData(newData);
}, [age]);
```